PM measurements given interval in Greece/Europe
I live in Greece. PM10 measurements are available from the MEEN (Ministry of Environment and Energy)  with a daily interval until 2016, and with an hourly one since then.
In parallel, municipality of Thessaloniki provides the PM concentrations with a daily interval. (the measurements of pollutants from 2017 are not publicly available)
Thus, I would like to ask if there is any European directive about the interval of PM or pollutants in general about transitioning from daily to hourly interval.
Thanks,
Dimitris
